# Specify parameters with SQLMAP

Tags: sql-injection, sqlmap

I'm a student learning php & mysql development. i have setup a private lab ( VM ) inside my computer to test & learn how sql injection works. When things get harder i use sqlmap to exploit and later on study the requests it made to my test app using verbose mode & by capturing packets via wireshark. I came across a small problem and that's to specify the parameter in a URL to sqlmap to test.

```
http://localhost/vuln/test.php?feature=music&song=1
```

i want sqlmap to scan the parameter **song** so i tried these solutions

```
-u http://localhost/vuln/test.php?feature=music&song=1 --skip feature
-u http://localhost/vuln/test.php? --data="feature=music&song=1" -p song
```

Tried different variations by adding and removing quotes and equal signs , non worked. I even tried setting the --risk to --level to its maximum but it still fails to pick up the last parameter.

I will be very thankful if an expert can help me out with this.
Thank you.

Answer (score 24):

the p option can be used in the following way

`-u "http://localhost/vuln/test.php?feature=music&song=1" -p song`

Comment: Also be careful that without quotes the command is not working properly.

Answer (score 6):

I noticed also that you can scan multiple parameters using this :

```
-u "http://localhost/vuln/test.php?feature=music&song=1" -p 'song,feature'
```

This will scan the `song` parameter, then the `feature` parameter.
If `sqlmap` find a vulnerable parameter, it will ask you if you want to continue with the others.

Answer (score 4):

You can simply add * to your value of parameter which you want to scan. Did you try that one?

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: -u http://localhost/vuln/test.php?feature=music&song=1*

if it is kind of POST request

-u http://localhost/vuln/test.php --data="feature=music&song=1*"

Comment: btw you dont need to use question-mark on sqlmapping POST requests. test.php is enough.

Answer (score 3):

I have this problem too. I think sqlmap inject the first parameter. If you type :

```
-u http://localhost/vuln/test.php?feature=music&song=1
```

sqlmap will inject 'feature' parameter. To make it inject 'song' parameter you need to reorder the parameter as follows :

```
-u http://localhost/vuln/test.php?song=1&feature=music
```

Dont forget to add '&' between each parameter. It worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I have already triggered this type of problem. You can simply skip the 'feature' parameter. E.g -u http:// localhost/vuln/test.php?feature=music&song=1 --skip=feature and then certainly it will start testing the 'song' parameter.